# get all available content type in Site Pages

Tags: content-type, sitepages

I want to get all available content type under Site Page :

```
Get-PnPContentType -List $listName
```

give me only : 
Wiki Page, Folder, Web Part Page, Site Page, Repost Page.

but actually, this what I have : 
[image]

Any idea how can get all content types ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link for getting content type for list
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcontenttype?view=sharepoint-ps '

and you can try for 
Get-PnPContentType -List listname